# IOS Swift NSLayoutConstraint. Unable to setup views horizontally centered

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

Im trying center all the view horizontally centered and with vertical spacing of 40. Email and password field shows. However login and signup button does not show up at all.

```
    view.addSubview(emailidTextField)
    view.addSubview(passwordTextField)
    view.addSubview(loginButton)
    view.addSubview(signupButton)

    passwordTextField.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.width - 20))
    passwordTextField.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40))

    emailidTextField.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: emailidTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.width - 20))
    emailidTextField.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: emailidTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40))


    loginButton.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: loginButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.width - 20))
    loginButton.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: loginButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40))

    signupButton.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: signupButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.width - 20))
    signupButton.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: signupButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40))

    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterXWithinMargins, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterXWithinMargins, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterYWithinMargins, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterYWithinMargins, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: emailidTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterXWithinMargins, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterXWithinMargins, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: emailidTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: passwordTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: -10))

    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: loginButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: loginButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: passwordTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 40))

    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: signupButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: signupButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: loginButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 40))

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7989a9e0 UIButton:0x79990040'Signup'.centerX == UIView:0x79c87d70.centerX>
```

I have centered Password field horizontally and vertically. Then use that as reference to space other views vertically. Any pointers on what im doing wrong?

Comment: You are setting NSLayoutAttribute.CenterXWithinMargins to two views, first one is passwordTextField and second one is emailidTextField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constraint are working fine, i have tried same in my code and it is working as you are expecting, just i have added some of the properties to showcase the button and textFields,

[image]

The edited code for constraint is as below,

let emailidTextField = UITextField()
        emailidTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line
        emailidTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        emailidTextField.placeholder = "Email Id"

```
    let passwordTextField = UITextField()
    passwordTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line
    passwordTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    passwordTextField.placeholder = "Password"

    let loginButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    loginButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    loginButton.setTitle("Login", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    loginButton.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    let signupButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    signupButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    signupButton.setTitle("Sign Up", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    loginButton.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    signupButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()


    view.addSubview(emailidTextField)
    view.addSubview(passwordTextField)
    view.addSubview(loginButton)
    view.addSubview(signupButton)

    passwordTextField.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.width - 20))
    passwordTextField.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40))

    emailidTextField.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: emailidTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.width - 20))
    emailidTextField.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: emailidTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40))


    loginButton.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: loginButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.width - 20))
    loginButton.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: loginButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40))

    signupButton.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: signupButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.width - 20))
    signupButton.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: signupButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40))

    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterXWithinMargins, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterXWithinMargins, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterYWithinMargins, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterYWithinMargins, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: emailidTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterXWithinMargins, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterXWithinMargins, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: emailidTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: passwordTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: -10))

    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: loginButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: loginButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: passwordTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 40))

    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: signupButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: signupButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: loginButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 40))
```

Comment: Cheers! Happy coding.